# como obtener la celda seleccionada de un gridControl devexpress

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, devexpress

Tengo un problema con devexpress? intento obtener el valor de una celda seleccionada en un gridControl, en un datagridview normal de windows form lo hacía así:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

Pero con el gridControl que trae devexpress no funciona.. con que código se puede hacer de la misma manera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo resolví así

```
 ColumnView view = gridControl1.MainView as ColumnView;
        int[] selectedRowHandles = view.GetSelectedRows();
        view.FocusedRowHandle = selectedRowHandles[0];
        view.CopyToClipboard();
        string valor = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(selectedRowHandles[0], view.Columns["Usuario"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez puedas usar el método GetSelectedRows del GridView para devolver una matriz con los  identificadores de fila seleccionados. Luego para obtener el valor de una celda de esa fila puedes usar el método GetRowCellValue del GridView.

```
int[] SelectedRowHandles = dataGridView1.GetSelectedRows();  

string Valor = dataGridView1.GetRowCellValue(SelectedRowHandles[0], 
                                             dataGridView1.Columns[1]);
```

Puedes obtener el GridView del GridControl así:

```
GridView dataGridView1 = gridControl1.MainView as GridView;
```

Comment: No funciona, es un gridControl y eso solo funciona con dataGridView

Comment: He extendido la respuesta.

Comment: Ahora dice 'SelectedRowHandles' no existe en el contexto actual

Comment: SelectedRowHandles es un array local

Comment: solo se debe  de agregar el toString al final

Answer (score 0):

la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/362897/189253) de [Antonio S.F.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/173473/antonio-s-f) esta bien, a mi me funciono solo debes agregarle el
.ToString() al final

```
        GridView dataGridView1 = gridControl1.MainView as GridView;
        int[] SelectedRowHandles = dataGridView1.GetSelectedRows();

        string Valor = dataGridView1.GetRowCellValue(SelectedRowHandles[0],
                                                     
        dataGridView1.Columns[0]).ToString();
```